# How to reset autoform-select2 input box

Tags: meteor, jquery-select2, meteor-autoform

## Background

I use Meteor to develop a web app.

I installed the following packages:

```
aldeed:autoform                    5.3.0
aldeed:collection2                 2.3.1
aldeed:autoform-select2            2.0.2
natestrauser:select2               3.5.1
zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css       1.4.6
```

## Question

I used a `select2` input box in an autoform, but after I submit the form, the input box does not reset. How do I get it to reset (i.e. clear the content)?

The initial input box:
[image: The initial input box]

After inserting values, which does not reset even after submit
[image: After inserting values, which does not reset even after submit]

This is the Simple Schemas definition:

```
Schemas.TutorialSession = new SimpleSchema({
    students: {
        type: [Number],
        label: "Students",
        autoform: {
            type: "select2",
            afFieldInput: {
                multiple: true
            },
            options: function() {
                return [{
                    label: "Student1",
                    value: 111
                }, {
                    label: "Student2",
                    value: 222
                }, {
                    label: "2015",
                    value: 333
                }];
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I opened an issue for this about a month ago, but still no solution. There's also a similar issue open for autoform in general, where using the same template to perform an update, then an insert will carry the values over from the last update. https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-select2/issues/35 This appears to be a problem with the way the package stores state information, in the event of a hot code update.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Appreciate it.